# Removing a known subset of items from a c++ vector

Tags: c++, vector, boost, stl

Given:

- `struct Item { int id; ... };`
- `std::vector<Item> items;`
- `std::vector<int> idsToRemove;`

What's the most efficient / cleanest way to write the code that performs the removal (while retaining order)?

Using `remove_if`, this could be:

```
items.erase(std::remove_if(items.begin(), items.end(),
    [&](const Item& i) {
        return std::find(idsToRemove.begin(), idsToRemove.end(), i.id)
            != idsToRemove.end();
    }), items.end());
```

Another way might be:

```
for (auto id : idsToRemove)
{
    items.erase(std::remove(items.begin(), items.end(), id), items.end());
    // or items.erase(std::find(items.begin(), items.end(), id));
    // provided that we know id always exists in items
}
```

Neither of these feel particularly nice (and they both seem *O(N*M)*), though the second seems tidier than the first.  Is there a better way?

(If it helps, while neither vector is sorted, it is known that `idsToRemove` is a subset of ids in the same order that they appear in `items`, and that both arrays are small.  And I can use Boost algorithms if there's something suitable over there.)

Comment: You can restrict the erase-remove to the subrange delimited by the first item matching the *next* ID. And if you do that from the back, you can minimise the amount of moving.

Comment: No, as noted the arrays are typically small.  I'm primarily looking for brevity of code, but I don't want it to be needlessly inefficient either.

Comment: If it were large arbitrary lists, I would have made a hash or bloom filter of idsToRemove, so you can check them in O(1) time as you iterate through items. But that's completely unnecessary given the same order subset guarantee. Since you said the vectors are small, O(NM) isn't all that bad, but I voted for 1201ProgramAlarm's answer. It is O(N) space and time, but you'll have to write it yourself. I think the real problem with your quick solutions above is that deleting a bunch of single items from a vector is itself a slow process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the ids in `idsToRemove` are known to be in `items` and in the same order, you can use a couple of iterators into `items` to keep track of the current compare element, the current destination, and walk thru `idsToRemove` and `items`, comparing both elements, moving the ones that you want to keep.  At the end of that process, resize `items` to be the new smaller size.

Comment: This sounds like writing a custom `remove_if`.

Comment: I was mostly asking to see if there was an existing STL or Boost algorithm or composite that already did removal of a vector from a vector (this seems like it ought to be something common, no?).  The sizes of the arrays aren't really big enough to justify doing anything complicated.

Comment: You could use a custom `remove_if`, but there'd be some complexities in the comparison (you'd be comparing the tail elements in `items` once you get to the end of `idsToRemove` and you'd need to check for that end before the dereffing the iterator).

Comment: The key insight here is that you can iterate once across items, and you can compare to idsToRemove by iterating across it once ever. You never back up because you know it is a subset in the same order. I got confused by the multiple iterators, but you're talking about using the original vector to shuffle things in place so you never get hit with the performance hit of vector delete. (Took me a minute to get what you were saying.)

Comment: @Miral: actually STL doesn't provide such facility because it's not common. It's an edge case to have a vector which is subset of another vector with the additional guarantee that elements are in the same order as the first. In any case it's quite trivial to do it keeping both iterators (so more efficiently) in a few lines of code.

Comment: True, knowing that they're in the same order is more unusual, but removing several items in general seems like it should be more common.  `remove_if` sort of covers that case, but it's a pretty fugly solution.  Also, given that range-based-for doesn't allow you to remove items during iteration, I would expect that iterate-to-build-list-of-things-to-delete then iterate-to-delete would become more common in code that uses it, and that would have similar preconditions.

Comment: std::remove_if from <algorithm> does move the items then drop the excess.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove

Answer (score 0):

I don't consider this a real answer to the question as stated (since it moves the goalposts), but it's something I found while investigating it and it may be of use to future searches.

In the case where you don't have the `idsToRemove` passed in externally, but need to iterate through the `items` anyway to decide which to remove, then there's a fairly nice way to do this in O(N):

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm_ext/erase.hpp>

boost::range::remove_erase_if(items, [&](const Item& item)
{
    // do whatever else you want to item
    // return true to erase the item, or
    return false; // to keep it
});
```

Internally it's based around `std::remove_if`, but it's much tidier and resembles range-based-for.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your elements have unique IDs, so instead of storing the elements to remove in an `std::vector`, just store them in an `std::unordered_set`.

This way, the `std::remove_if` way is really clean:

```
struct Item {
    int id;
};

// ...
std::vector<Item> items;
std::unordered_set<int> idsToRemove;
items.erase(
    std::remove_if(std::begin(items), std::end(items), [&](Item const& it) {
            return (idsToRemove.find(it.id) != std::end(idsToRemove));
        }),
    std::end(items));
```

Complexity (amortized) will be `O(N)` where `N` is the number of elements in the vector.